# Excluding non-integers input

Tags: c++, cin

I'm trying to output `"Rose"` when `S` is a positive integer and `>= 5`.
However, when I input `5.1`, the output is still `"Rose"`.
I can't figure it out:(
[edit: I forgot to say that S is an odd positive number, that's why I include `S%2 == 1` in my code]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int S;
    cout << "Please input the size of a rose: " << endl;
    cin >> S;
    if (S%2 == 1 && S >= 5 && sizeof(S) == 4) {
        cout << "Rose" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Invalid input size!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(S) == 4` this is pointless. Please read more about how `sizeof` works https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: An integer can not contain a `.` and parsing stops at the first character that can not be part of the representation of the parsed type.

Comment: `sizeof(S)` is exactly the same as `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: `S%2 == 1` does not mean that `S` is a positive integer. That it is positive follows from `S >=  5`, so it's not clear what the positive condition is for.

Comment: [Trying to learn about validation loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406754/trying-to-learn-about-input-validation-loops/60423428#60423428) will be helpful, just replace `double` with `int`.

Comment: To be clear, an input like `5.0` would be considered valid (odd positive integer >= 5) or are you accepting only odd positive `int` >= 5?

Answer (score 0):

S has "int" type, so when you enter 5.1, only 5 will be read into S. One solution is to read S1 as a double (or string, etc), and check if it represent an integer, If so, convert them to int and store them in S, otherwise print an error message.