# Beginner C++ Voting Program using const literal

Tags: c++, switch-statement, constants, literals

This program I came across on another forum is a voting program, someone was having issues with compiling. Any answer that was given didn't really match up with what the programmer wanted. So I am here to get some effective answers after attempting to edit the code myself.

The current issue I am having is when I input the variable, it still runs an infinite loop. What am I not doing properly for the design to perform, until I input 5 votes?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int ev = 5; //max. # of votes
int votesA = 0, votesB = 0, votesC = 0, spoiltvotes = 0; //total votes already initialized globally
int vote; //input variable

int main()
{
    //loop over the voting stations
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= ev; i++)
   
   {
    //loop over the votes
    cout << "Enter your vote: \t";
    cin >> vote;
    while(vote <= 5)
    {

        switch(vote)
        {
            case 1: votesA++;
            break;

            case 2: votesB++;
            break;

            case 3: votesC++;
            break;

            default: spoiltvotes++;
        }

    }
   } 
    //display results neatly
    cout << "# of votes for candidate A: \t" << votesA;
    cout << "\n # of votes for candidate B: \t" << votesB;
    cout << "\n # of votes for candidate C: \t" << votesC;
    cout << "\n # of spoilt votes: \t" << spoiltvotes;

    return 0;
}
```

Updated Result: I have fixed the infinite loop but for some reason the loop is still iterating 6 times instead of 5, giving me large tallies of numbers instead of single-digits.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int ENDvote = 5; //max. # of votes

    //loop over the voting stations
    int vote;
    int spoiltvotes;
    for(vote = 0; vote >= ENDvote; vote++)
    cout << "1. Candidate A\t 2. Candidate B\t 3. Candidate C" << endl;
   
   {
    //loop over the votes
    cout << "Enter your vote: \t";
    cin >> vote;

        switch(vote)
        {
            case 1:
            cout << "# of votes for candidate A:\t" << vote;
            break;

            case 2:
            cout << "# of votes for candidate B:\t" << vote;
            break;

            case 3:
            cout << "# of votes for candidate C:\t" << vote;
            break;

            default:
            cout << "# of spoilt votes:\t" << spoiltvotes;
            break;
        }
   } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The inner loop will keep asking for votes until the user enters a number greater than `5`. I don't think you want that. In fact, I don't think you want the `while` loop at all.

Comment: This is not input regarding performace, but in `cin >> vote;` you don't know you got a value from the user, yet you let it go.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i <= ev; i++)` will actually iterate 6 times. You may want to use just `<` instead. Figured you might not know since the comment `//max. # of votes` implies you want 5 votes, not 6.

Comment: The inner loop `while(vote <= 5)` will continue forever if it begins, since none of the code in the loop body can modify the value of `vote`.

Comment: Proper indentation would make it easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried entering `6` for the vote to end your current loop?  You further need to learn how to validate your input. You must check the stream state after each input against `eofbit`, `badbit` and `failbit`. See [std::ios_base::iostate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) And see answer to [Trying to learn about input validation loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423428/3422102)

Answer (score 1):

There is an obvious issue to your code.
When you enter your for loop : ‘for(i = 0; i <= ev; i++)’ you get to the ‘cin>>vote;’ When you get the vote if ‘vote<=5’ the loop with go on forever due to the while loop. Once you enter the while loop VOTE NEVER CHANGES. So, if the while loop condition is fulfilled, it will always be true since(again) vote doesn’t change.

Fred Larson said what I am saying essentially.

I am new to stack overflow so anything you think I should be doing, please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already commented on what's the problem with your program, the while loop would never break since `vote` is never getting updated and if the input value in `vote` is `<=5`, it shall remain to be so and end up being an infinite while loop.

A while loop within a for loop is ***usually*** not something you'd want and should look hard at the code and see if that's what you *really* want. If not, refactor it out to stick with either one of them, not both.

Your problem appears to be in a similar vein. From your program, it seems that you want to read in the votes polled at the 5 voting stations and then count the number of votes that each candidate received (or went waste).

If you go the for loop route, you just need to iterate over the loop, read in the number of votes (alongwith input validations), do the switch case and then move on to the next iteration of the for loop.

If you go the while loop route, then just have a while loop to read in five votes, something like

```
while(std::cin>>vote) {
     switch(...
```

and do pretty much the same stuff.

Also, global variables are (again) [***usually***](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/why-global-variables-are-evil/) a bad idea, especially if they are non-`const`. Move them into your `main()`.

Also, do take care that a `break` statement only breaks the inner-most loop. So, doing something like

```
while(true) {
    int x = 1;
    switch(x) {
        case 1:
        break;
    }
}
```

will *not* break the while loop,.

Comment: When I find myself in a conundrum of nested loops or `switch` in loop, I pull the loop out and put it into its own function. When you find the loop exit condition, rather than a `break` that can't get all the way out, you can `return` from the function and get out of all of the loops, `switch`s, or what-have-you.

Comment: I figured out the loop iteration part but for some reason I am still getting large tallies of numbers in my results. I edited my post for updated result. Would one of you mind checking that out? @magmamite125

Comment: @Japer See if looking at `vote = 0; vote >= ENDvote;` helps? You are starting from 0 but...rings a bell as to why the 6 iterations?

Comment: I had thought so as well, until I entered 1 in `vote = 0;` and it still gave me the same tallies of votes. I even tried deleting `const int ENDvote = 5;` to see if it would give my expected result, but it still gave the exact tallies. I'm wondering if I need to update the tasks.json and settings.json files in VS code.

Comment: @Japer `for(vote = 0; vote >= ENDvote; vote++)` should be changed to `for(idx= 0; idx < ENDvote; idx++)` to have 5 iterations.